# Filled natural transformations

Tags: ct.category-theory

According to the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lift), a commutative square

[image: 2]

can be viewed as a 'lifting problem' between $f$ and $g$, and a solution to this lifting problem is a morphism $\ell:B\to C$ filling the above square, so

[image: 3]

commutes. Taking this view, a natural transformation $\alpha:F\Rightarrow G$ is a collection of lifting problems between the images of $F$ and $G$ on Hom-sets.

> Is the notion of a 'solved' or 'filled' natural transformation, such that for each arrow $f:X\to Y$ in the domain category we have a filled square, useful or studied anywhere?

By a filled natural transformation square for $f$ I mean a commutative square as below

[image: 4]

This seems superficially related to the notion of a pseudonatural transformation, where $\ell_f$ would be replaced by an isomorphic $2$-cell satisfying coherence diagrams, but I'm not sure there's any actual connection. I would also be interested in the notion of an 'orthogonal transformation', where each $\ell_f$ is unique so $F(f)$ and $G(f)$ are orthogonal for all $f$.

Comment: Just a note: Lifting problems are almost always drawn with the diagonal filler going upwards-rightwards, not downwards-leftwards as you have here. Of course it’s formally the same, but the convention is very helpful for readability and distinguishing the roles of the morphisms involved, so I’d recommend following it except when there’s a clear reason not to.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Will do, I’m walking my dog at the moment but I’ll edit when I get home.

Comment: This seems highly related to the notion of "coherent" or "natural" lifts that we use in the study of categorical models of type theory. I'm on mobile, but perhaps see "Natural models of homotopy type theory" by Steve Awodey and look at the discussion around the elimination rule for the intensional identity type.

Comment: @DanielGratzer I’ll check it out, thanks for the reference.